# FCM notification with action button

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to show custom notification with action button if the `onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage)` in `FirebaseMessagingService` called only in foreground, and in background the default notification is shown?

From docs:

> When in the background, apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification.
>
> When in the foreground, your app receives a message object with both
> payloads available.

[doc link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages)

I am sending `data messages` via rest api

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send


{
    "to": "my-token",
    "notification": {
      "title": "test title",
      "body": "test body"
      },

   "data": {
    "url": "test url",
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like only when `notification{}` field is used `onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage)` ignored in backgound.

Works with:

```
    {
      "to": "my-token",
      "data": {
      "url": "test url",
      }
    }
```